# Detect if the VM is copied

Tags: c#, vb.net, virtual-machine

I have developed a program using VB.NET, in form OnLoad I check for Disk serial number, UUID for licensing purposes.

That works well if the exe is moved to other PC, it gives a message that the Program is not licensed to work on this PC.

My problem now is: If the program is installed on Virtual Machine, and the VM is copied, I can not detect that. All Data are the same, HD serial number, UUID are the same.

I can not depend on MAC address since if no Network is assigned to the VM, then the MAC will be the same for Original and copied VM (Empty MAC).

Any Idea how to detect if the program is on a copied VM?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its really important to ask questions properly here. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. This site is for questions regarding specific issues with existing code. As it stands, your question is off-topic because you don't explain what behaviour you're  getting and what errors you get and on what line they occur. Don't let negative votes or votes to close put you off though. Thanks

Comment: @David: That's a total misunderstanding.  Conceptual questions are allowed.  Questions about programming environments are allowed.  Algorithm questions are allowed.  Do not go around commenting on questions simply because there is no code and no error message, instead take a closer look and see whether it is a type of question that demands code.